# WORDPRESS FORM ACTION HELP

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Создал форму, заполнил одно поле, хочу чтобы эта страница обновилась и вывела то, что я заполнил. Вот маленький код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" class="info-profile">
<input type="text" name="name" value="ROBERT SMITH">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["name"])) 
 { echo " Получены новые вводные: имя - ".$_POST["name"];} 
 else { echo "Переменные не дошли. Проверьте все еще раз."; }
?>
</html>
```

Проблема в том, что данный код на локалке работает идеально, а вот на странице вордпреса я нажимаю отправить и он выдаёт сообщение - этой страницы не найдено. Как быть?

Comment: Я хоть и плохо знаю php но я один не вижу вызова? Да и вообще какой либо функции?

Comment: Если нет ничего в action, то он вызывает сам себя. 
Зачем функции, echo должен вывести то, что мы введём в поле.

Comment: @Станислав проверьте правильность путей.

Comment: Пути правильные, плюс он же вызывает сам себя.

Comment: В каком файле код прописываете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположение, что какой-либо код php будет выполняться на html-странице - неверное.

Надо создать файл .php. В нем:

```
<?php
?>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="info-profile">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="ROBERT SMITH">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php
    if (!empty($_POST["name"]))
        { echo " Получены новые вводные: имя - ".$_POST["name"];}
        else { echo "Переменные не дошли. Проверьте все еще раз."; }
?>
```

Посмотрите, как это работает на моем тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/so/632157.php

**UPDATE**

В результате уточнения вопроса выяснилось, что автор создал страницу WordPress и установил для нее свой php-шаблон. В php-файле шаблона есть следующий фрагмент:

```
?>
<form action="" method="POST" class="info-profile">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="ROBERT SMITH">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["name"])) 
 { echo " Получены новые вводные: имя - ".$_POST["name"];} 
 else { echo "Переменные не дошли. Проверьте все еще раз."; }
?>
```

При нажатии на кнопку выводится ошибка 404.

Так происходит потому, что есть [перечень зарезервированных слов в WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms), которые не должны присутствовать в GET и POST запросах. Слово `name` находится в этом списке.

Вот как примерно должен выглядеть файл шаблона для страницы:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: cv
*/
?>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="info-profile">
        <input type="text" name="cv_name" value="ROBERT SMITH">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['cv_name']) ) {
        echo " Получены новые вводные: имя - " . $_POST["cv_name"];
    }
    else {
        echo "Переменные не дошли. Проверьте все еще раз.";
    }
?>
```

Посмотреть работающий пример можно [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so632157/).

Comment: объединил вопросы

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>"
```