# WordPress form action Вызов данной страницы

Tags: php, wordpress, form, action, submit

Здравствуйте. Создал форму, заполнил одно поле, хочу чтобы эта страница обновилась и вывела то, что я заполнил. Вот маленький код:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="info-profile">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="ROBERT SMITH">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST["name"])) 
     { echo " Получены новые вводные: имя - ".$_POST["name"];} 
     else { echo "Переменные не дошли. Проверьте все еще раз."; }
    ?>
    </html>
```

Проблема в том, что данный код на локалке работает идеально, а вот на странице вордпреса я нажимаю отправить и он выдаёт сообщение - этой страницы не найдено. Как быть?

Comment: Вам уже был дан ответ на это здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632157/wordpress-form-action-help